# Divisão por zero em double = resultado Infinity

Tags: java, divisão

Eu estava aprendendo sobre tratamento de erros na linguagem Java e fiz testes com o código de exemplo da aula em questão. Em um teste eu adicionei `(double)` na operação final para deixar o resultado mais preciso e notei que, depois disso, quando eu tentava dividir um número qualquer "x" por "0", ao invés do erro "ArithmeticException" eu recebia um "Infinity" como resultado.

Por que isso ocorre? E por que isso só ocorre para operações com números de ponto flutuante (visto que, com a operação em inteiros, ocorreu o erro normalmente)?

Segue o código:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean continua = true;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Numerador: ");
                int a = s.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Denominador: ");
                int b = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("O resultado da divisão foi: " + (double) a / b);

                s.close();
                continua = false;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e1) {
                System.err.println("Informe um número inteiro");
                s.nextLine();
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e2) {
                System.err.println("Denominador deve ser diferente de zero");
                s.nextLine();
            }
        } while (continua);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2

Comment: Nenhum número tanto inteiro como real pode ser dividido por zero. Isso não é da logica de programação, e sim da matemática.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2381633/6809703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os tipos float e double implementam o padrão IEEE 754, que define que uma divisão por zero deve retornar um valor especial "infinito".

Lançar exception, como no tipo int, violaria este padrão.